# How to populate AngularJS nested category dropdowns?

Tags: angularjs

On my backend, I have a nested categories structure like this:

```
Category
--------
id
parent_id
name
```

That I load completely into `$scope.categories` as a single dimension array.

On screen, I want to show one dropdown per level, showing the correspondent path. For example, if the path is cars/sedan/ford/taurus, I want to show four dropdowns:

> <kbd>Cars v</kbd> <kbd>Sedans v</kbd> <kbd>Ford v</kbd> <kbd>Taurus v</kbd>

Whenever a dropdown is changed, the ones to the right should be deleted, and the immediate one populated with all child categories whose parent is the one I just selected. Regular stuff.

I also created a `category_path` array that contains each category_id in the path to the product category: `[null, category_id, category_id, category_id]`.

And then I did this:

```
<select
    ng-repeat="item in category_path"
    ng-model="selected_category[$index]"
    ng-options="category.name for category in (categories | filter : { parent_id: item } : true ) track by category.id "
    ng-change="select_category(selected_category[$index], $index)"
    ></select>
```

On my controller:

```
$scope.select_category = function ( selected_category, index ) {

    if ( $filter('filter') ($scope.categories, { parent_id: selected_category.id }, true).length ) {
        if ( $scope.category_path[index+1] != undefined ) {
            $scope.category_path = $scope.category_path.slice(0, index+1);
            $scope.category_path[index+1] = selected_category.id;
        } else {
            $scope.category_path.push( selected_category.id );
        }
    } else {
        $scope.product.category_id = selected_category.id;
    }

}
```

This works like charm, except for the fact that I can't populate the default values for each dropdown, based on the current product `category_path` array.

I tried:

```
ng-init="select_category[$index] = category_path[$index]"
```

without success. Ideas?

Comment: Can you copy the `category_path` array to `select_category` in the controller? Before or after the function you provided? This should be executed when the controller gets included so the list should be initialized correctly.

Comment: @ShellFish you mean `$scope.selected_category = angular.copy( $scope.category_path );`? Did so, it didn't work.

Comment: No I mean as in `angular.copy( $scope.category_path, $scope.selected_category);`. Be sure **not** to include this *inside* the function.

Comment: @ShellFish not working either.

Comment: That's because `select_category` isn't an array in your example apparently, it's a function. Which array holds the values that you want inside the ´category_path´ array?

Comment: @ShellFish the `category_path` array is already properly populated. `select_category` is the name of the function triggered on select change. `selected_category` is the name of the ng-model tied to the multiple selects (it's tied as `ng-model=selected_category[$index]`). Is this a proper way to go?

Comment: Oh sorry, dyslectic misread for me there. I don't see why the copy doesn't work. Try to execute it in the init of the parent div maybe?

Comment: @ShellFish `ng-init="angular.copy( category_path, selected_category );"` Didn't work either. Creating a plunkr now :D.

Comment: May be a good idea, this is strange behavior... I'm sure we'll find out soon enough when we can toy around with it.

Comment: @ShellFish http://plnkr.co/edit/Ljg4b4ZOUDFKT0lLGI3h

Comment: For one thing, the entries in your `category_path` array differ from the entries in your select dropdown. `console.log` the values, perhaps that's where your issue lies? The array holds `null, 1, 2` in the plunker...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78961/discussion-between-mauro-and-shellfish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `category_path` array holds different values than the model, i.e. the `selected_category` array. The latter seems to hold JSON strings while the former holds a single value (for the `id` key).

To make the default values work, insert the full JSON objects into the model array.